# Is there any new interface that has been introduce with dotnet framework 4.0?

Tags: .net, interface

Curious to know if any has been because googling didnot helped much.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are plenty of new interfaces, e.g. `IDynamicMetaObjectProvider` and `IProducerConsumerCollection<T>`. Take a look at the list of [new features](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171868.aspx).